# Service onDestroy called without onStartCommand

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm getting reports of a `NullPointerException` when the `onDestroy()` service method gets called. The part that i don't understand is that i always start the service with a `Context.startService()` so the `onStartCommand()` should always be called and the reference should never be null.

It is worth mentioning, that the `NullPointerException` doesn't happen when i shutdown the service with `Context.stopService()` call.

So my conclusion is that the framework is calling `onDestroy()` without having called `onStartCommand()`. I'm guessing that the Service might be being destroyed, and restarted by the framework so `onStartCommand()` doesn't actually gets executed. But again, this is me just guessing.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? Thanks!

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class ServiceLocationListener extends Service 

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        mNotificationManager = getService(this, Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(SOME_NOTIFICATION_ID, someNotification);
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mNotificationManager.cancel(SOME_NOTIFICATION_ID);  <<<<<<<<< NPE
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put mNotificationManager = getService(this, Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); in onCreat() of service.

Comment: Right, this would be my first attempt to fix it on the next release, as i don't have a way to locally reproduce it. However, do you know what the insight on this behavior is ?

Comment: Little strange, but there could be issue with memory, and system not allowing to properly start and destroying it immediately. But I think you mentioned like if call Context.stopService() its not giving nullpointer. So its means like your service run once properly. right?

Comment: Right, stopService gets executed just fine, so there's some special scenario where the onStartCommand has not been called ( not in my code ) and therefore the npe. Thanks!